# How to show different no. of images over image?

Tags: html, css, image

I need to place some images over background image. I am able to place images over background image. But the problem is that the no. of images to be placed over background image is not fixed and also images to be placed change everytime. For example, sometimes I need to place 4 images over background image and sometimes I need to 5 images and so on. I can not change code everytime.

How can I dynamically place images over background image ?

Code I have used to place images over background image is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Show Image over image</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
img { position:absolute; top: 25px; z-index: 2;}
.imgA1 { left: 0px; } 
.imgB1 { left: 20px; } 
.imgB2 { left: 15px; } 
.imgB3 { left: 30px; } 
.imgB4 { left: 45px; } 
.imgB5 { left: 60px; } 
.imgB6 { left: 75px; } 
.imgB7 { left: 90px; } 
.imgB8 { left: 105px; } 
.imgB9 { left: 120px; } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="background.png" style="z-index: 1;" class="imgA1"/>
<img src="a_0s.png" class="imgB1" />
<img src="line.gif" class="imgB2" />
<img src="line.gif" class="imgB3" />
<img src="line.gif" class="imgB4" />
<img src="line.gif" class="imgB5" />
<img src="line.gif" class="imgB6" />
<img src="line.gif" class="imgB7" />
<img src="line.gif" class="imgB8" />
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0d/Yellow_star.gif" class="imgB9" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve but my first impression is that this will require Javascript

Comment: @Paulie_D : Due to less reputation points I m not able to post image, but a link to what I want to achieve is as follows: [link] (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/larryz/clipart/clipart.png). Its fine if I have to use Javascript. Can you suggest a way ? Thing is that in my code above I need to specify style of each beforehand. I need something that can specify style of each image automatically. Thanks!

Comment: Js can help with positioning but styling is best left to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use a css background image then just add the images.

```css
body {background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/g/700/700");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;width:100%;height:500px;} 
img{border:1px solid red;margin:10px;}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/20" width="40" height="20" />
```

Comment: Problem is not to add more images its about adding variable no. of images without changing code everytime. Thanks!

Comment: I only added loads of images for example. Use css background image and it doesn't matter about how many images you add, the code won't change